# Can a countable set contain uncountably many infinite subsets such that the intersection of any two such distinct subsets is finite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can a countable set contain uncountably many infinite subsets such that the intersection of any two such distinct subsets is finite?

Comment: Not sure about $\mathfrak c$-many, but $\omega_1$-many -- yes, I think.

Comment: @tomasz: continuum many is perfectly doable.

Comment: Such system of sets is called [almost disjoint family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_disjoint_sets). See e.g. [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2002;task=show_msg;msg=0239.0001).

Comment: This is problem 13, page 27, of Kaplansky's "Set theory and metric spaces".

Comment: Since this is the canonical duplicate I've decided to edit its title to make it easier to find. I invite people to help improve this question in other ways as well.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes. For every $r\in\mathbb R$ choose a sequence of rational numbers $\{r_n\in\mathbb Q\mid n\in\mathbb  N\}$ which converges monotonically to $r$, this sequence is of course a subset of $\mathbb Q$ - a countable set.

If $r\neq s$ are two real numbers then the sequence we chose for them must intersect at a finite subset, otherwise we had a subsequence of the two which would converge to two different limit points.

Since $\mathbb R$ is uncountable (and in fact has cardinality as $\mathcal P(\mathbb Q)$) we have indeed uncountably many subsets of $\mathbb Q$ with the wanted property.

Comment: @pritam: By Cantor's theorem it is not countable.

Comment: @pritam he's considering subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$, which is countable. So it meets your conditions exactly.

Comment: @pritam: And $\mathbb Q$ is not a countable set?

Comment: @Mark: Good idea. Thanks!

Comment: One can remark that this is essentially why the real numbers are uncountable in particular when constructed with Dedekind cuts, perhaps.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If I want to prove it for a general countable set, $X$ , would it be correct to say that there is a bijection, $f$,  from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $X$ and for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ define the set $X_ \alpha$ as the set of all elements of the sequence  that converges to $\alpha$  (the same sequence in your solution) after applying $f$ on them and then the function $g: ({X_\alpha })_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $g(X_\alpha)=\alpha$ is a bijection?

Comment: @dorsh605: Yes, and perhaps a simpler way of doing that would be to define $F(\alpha)=\{f(q)\mid q\in X_\alpha\}$, where $f\colon\Bbb Q\to X$ is a bijection. Then $F$ is an injective function from $\Bbb R$ into $\mathcal P(X)$ such that any two distinct sets in its image have finite intersection.

Comment: @AsafKaragila did you mean $F(\alpha)=\{f(q){ }|{ }q\in \underline{S_\alpha}\}$ where $S_\alpha$ is the set of all elements in the sequence that converges to $\alpha$?

Comment: @dorsh605: Yes, your previous comment used $X_\alpha$ to denote the sequence converging to $\alpha$. Sorry for not predicting the future change to $S_\alpha$, my crystal ball is not with me right now. ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I only changed it because in my previous comment I defined the set $X_\alpha$ to be the set of elements of $S_\alpha$ after applying f on them i.e $X_\alpha = \{f(q) | q\in S_\alpha \}$

Comment: @dorsh605: Oh. I see now. Sorry, yes. $S_\alpha$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Why does such a sequence exist?

Comment: @Sahiba Arora: What sequence?

Comment: A sequence which converges monotonically to r.

Comment: @Sahiba Arora: For various reasons. Mainly because every convergent sequence in $\Bbb R$ has a monotonous subsequence. You can also enumerate the rational numbers, and proceed by induction to define a sequence which converges monotonically to $r$ from above or from below.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So you know, if you care so, your solution coincides with the "hint" given by the problem statement of Kaplansky's "Set theory and metric spaces" problem 13, page 27.

Comment: @Santropedro: I have never opened that book. It's a standard solution to this problem, and I learned it when I was an undergrad, from one of my friends.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Interesting thanks for letting me know that! I hope you didn't get offended (In case it happened, I don't have idea if it did).

Answer (score 9):

Let P be the set of all prime numbers, which is countable. Consider an infinite subset A = {$p_0,p_1,p_2...$} of primes from P arranged in an increasing order. We form $B_A$ = {$p_0,p_0p_1,p_0p_1p_2,...$} corresponding to A.

Now, the prime factorization is unique for integers. Thus, if we choose another infinite subset $A_1$ of P different from A then the corresponding $B_{A_1}$ and $B_A$ has only finitely many elements in common. Since P is countably infinite, the number of different infinite subsets of P is continuum. Hence we are done.

Comment: The definition of $B_A$ is really unclear.

Comment: $B_A$ = {${p_0,p_0*p_1,p_0*p_1*p_2,...}$}

Comment: I asked for a clarification, and you just rewrote the same thing that was unclear.

Comment: There is a one to one correspondence between A and $B_A$ . So, Now for different infinite subset $A_1$ and $A_2$ we get corresponding $B_{A_1}$ and $B_{A_2}$. Then we arise in 2 possible cases, 1. First finite terms in $B_{A_1}$ and $B_{A_2}$ are same. 2. Otherwise, both the sets would have been same,leading to $A_1$ = $A_2$ and that's a contradiction !

Comment: I still don't understand **how do you define $B_A$**??

Comment: Given an infinite subset of primes, A = {$p_0,p_1,...$}, I am forming a set $B_A$, the element $p_i$ in A is mapped to ($p_0*p_1*...*p_i$) in B. Can you please elaborate the problem ?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. We know $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are equipotent so we choose a bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$. We also know that $\mathbb{R}$ is equipotent to the set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$. For every $r \in \mathbb{R}$ choose $(q_{r,n})_n$ a representative from the equivalence class corresponding to $r$. Note that if $r_1\neq r_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ then $q_{r_1,n} = q_{r_2,n}$ for at most finitely many $n$. Since $f$ is a bijection we have that the sequences $(m_{r,n})_n := (f^{-1}(q_{r,n}))_n \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ share the same property. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable this concludes the proof; just choose the subset $N_\alpha$ to be the range of $m_\alpha$.

Answer (score 8):

Another Solution: 
Since $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ are equivalent, and cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\omega$, we can work on $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. Fix a $m \in \mathbb{R}$, let $A_m$ be the set of points $(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, that are of distance $\leq 1$ from the line $y = mx$. $A_m$ is infinite as it has a point on every vertical line x=k (k=0,1,2,...) and for any 2 lines $y = mx$ and $y= m_1x$ for $m \neq m_1$ , there are only finite number of points lying of distance $\leq$ 1 from both, so, $\ A_m\cap \ A_{m_1}$ is finite. These sets $\ A_m$ are the required subsets which are continuum many.

Answer (score 7):

For each $t\in(\frac1{10},1),$ take its decimal expansion (or one of its decimal expansions in case of non-uniqueness), and let $A_t$ be the set of all finite truncations of that decimal expansion, considered as positive integers. For example,
$$A_{\frac13}=\{3,\ 33,\ 333,\ 3333,\ 33333,\dots\},$$
$$A_{\pi-3}=\{1,\ 14,\ 141,\ 1415,\ 14159,\dots\}.$$

Answer (score 6):

Pick $S = \cup_{n \in \mathbb N} \{0;1\}^{\{1;2;\ldots;n\}}$, the set of functions from a finite set to $\{0;1\}$.
For any function $f : \mathbb N \to \{0;1\}$, let $g(f) = \{ f|_{\{1;2;\ldots;n\}}, n \in \mathbb N\}$ : $g(f)$ is the subset of $S$ containing all the restrictions of $f$.

Then the set $\{g(f), f : \mathbb N \to \{0;1\}\}$ is an uncountable subset of $\mathcal P(S)$ (because $g$ is injective and there are uncountably many functions $f$) where any two distinct subsets have finite intersection (if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are distinct, they disagree at some integer $n$, from which all their restrictions are different).

Also, this is almost the same as picking $S$ as the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, and $g : \mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to \mathcal P( S)$ the injection given by $g(X) = \{X \cap \{1 ; 2 ; \ldots n \}, n \in \mathbb N\}$.