# $\mathbb{N}$ with uncountably many infinite subsets

Tags: set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Countable set having uncountably many infinite subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162387/countable-set-having-uncountably-many-infinite-subsets)

Can the set $\mathbb{N}$, the set of natural numbers, contain uncountably many infinite subsets $(N_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}}$ such that $N_\alpha\cap N_\beta$ is finite if $\alpha\ne\beta$.